# How does TCP combine data when sending a big data packet which is over MSS?

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming, tcpdump

Here is a tcpdump demo.

- seq 1 - 52001 is big data, over my loopback MSS (16384).
- seq 52001 - 52013 is small data.

How does TCP know seq 1 - 52001 is a combined data block and seq 52001 - 52013 is another combined data block?

```
23:10:00.773752 IP localhost.56006 > localhost.30000: Flags [S], seq 3081455670, win 65535, options [mss 16344,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 807676974 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
23:10:00.774059 IP localhost.30000 > localhost.56006: Flags [S.], seq 1040822423, ack 3081455671, win 65535, options [mss 16344,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 3518795094 ecr 807676974,sackOK,eol], length 0
23:10:00.774101 IP localhost.56006 > localhost.30000: Flags [.], ack 1, win 6379, options [nop,nop,TS val 807676974 ecr 3518795094], length 0
23:10:00.774125 IP localhost.30000 > localhost.56006: Flags [.], ack 1, win 6379, options [nop,nop,TS val 3518795094 ecr 807676974], length 0
23:10:00.783835 IP localhost.56006 > localhost.30000: Flags [.], seq 1:16333, ack 1, win 6379, options [nop,nop,TS val 807676984 ecr 3518795094], length 16332
23:10:00.783840 IP localhost.56006 > localhost.30000: Flags [.], seq 16333:32665, ack 1, win 6379, options [nop,nop,TS val 807676984 ecr 3518795094], length 16332
23:10:00.783843 IP localhost.56006 > localhost.30000: Flags [.], seq 32665:48997, ack 1, win 6379, options [nop,nop,TS val 807676984 ecr 3518795094], length 16332
23:10:00.783847 IP localhost.56006 > localhost.30000: Flags [P.], seq 48997:52001, ack 1, win 6379, options [nop,nop,TS val 807676984 ecr 3518795094], length 3004
23:10:00.783861 IP localhost.56006 > localhost.30000: Flags [P.], seq 52001:52013, ack 1, win 6379, options [nop,nop,TS val 807676984 ecr 3518795094], length 12
23:10:00.783874 IP localhost.56006 > localhost.30000: Flags [F.], seq 52013, ack 1, win 6379, options [nop,nop,TS val 807676984 ecr 3518795094], length 0
23:10:00.784068 IP localhost.30000 > localhost.56006: Flags [.], ack 16333, win 6124, options [nop,nop,TS val 3518795104 ecr 807676984], length 0
23:10:00.784106 IP localhost.30000 > localhost.56006: Flags [.], ack 32665, win 5869, options [nop,nop,TS val 3518795104 ecr 807676984], length 0
23:10:00.784110 IP localhost.30000 > localhost.56006: Flags [.], ack 48997, win 5614, options [nop,nop,TS val 3518795104 ecr 807676984], length 0
23:10:00.784114 IP localhost.30000 > localhost.56006: Flags [.], ack 52001, win 5567, options [nop,nop,TS val 3518795104 ecr 807676984], length 0
23:10:00.784121 IP localhost.30000 > localhost.56006: Flags [.], ack 52013, win 5567, options [nop,nop,TS val 3518795104 ecr 807676984], length 0
23:10:00.784139 IP localhost.30000 > localhost.56006: Flags [.], ack 52014, win 5567, options [nop,nop,TS val 3518795104 ecr 807676984], length 0
23:10:00.798479 IP localhost.30000 > localhost.56006: Flags [F.], seq 1, ack 52014, win 5567, options [nop,nop,TS val 3518795119 ecr 807676984], length 0
23:10:00.798571 IP localhost.56006 > localhost.30000: Flags [.], ack 2, win 6379, options [nop,nop,TS val 807676999 ecr 3518795119], length 0
```

Here is my client code:

```
func main() {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:30000")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("dial failed, err", err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    msg := ""
    for i := 0; i < 2000; i++ {
        msg += `Hello, Hello. How are you?`

    }
    conn.Write([]byte(msg))

    conn.Write([]byte("demo content"))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> How does TCP know seq 1 - 52001 is a combined data block and seq 52001 - 52013 is another combined data block?

It doesn't. From the perspective of TCP this is only a byte stream without any internal structure. Any structure (like a "message") needs to be added by the application protocol.

Or in other words: you cannot expect that a single write/send in the sender will result in a single read/recv in the recpient.

Comment: - I might get it.

-  For example, I use http protocol which is over tcp. it content-length is a large size( over mss).
- The first packet get header and  body, and body don't meet the content length. so http client get next packet to combine the content . 
-  Is that right？

Comment: @zhouzzz: Kind of. The first read might not even get the full header though, so it might even need more reads to get the full header. And when it reads it might even get parts of the body already, so after each read it must check what is read so far against the APDU (application protocol data unit) semantics defined by the application protocol.